# TCPDF SVG does not get displayed

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to generate a document (this part works correctly) that must have a logo in the top right corner (this does not work).

What is the problem with my code here? I double checked the file exists and is readable. Tried to move things around, googled usage examples, but still stuck with TCPDF silently not displaying the image.

```
$generator = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
// set header and footer fonts
$generator->setPrintHeader(false);
$generator->setPrintFooter(false);
// set margins
$generator->SetMargins(10, 10, 10);


$generator->AddPage();
$generator->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);

$generator->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');

$generator->ImageSVG(
    $file = ('path/to/my/file.svg'),
    $x = 250,
    $y = -10,
    $w = '',
    $h = 50,
    $link = '',
    $align = '',
    $palign = '',
    $border = 0,
    $fitonpage = false);

return $generator->Output('generated.pdf', 'S');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Imagick to create a PNG directly from the SVG file and see if that opens OK:

```
$im = new Imagick('path/to/my/file.svg');
$im->setImageFormat( 'PNG24' );
$im->writeImage('path/to/my/file.png');
```

If that file displays OK, I'm not sure what the problem is. However, if that file doesn't display OK, then the problem may be in the underlying SVG file. Imagick is quite strict when checking attributes, etc, in the incoming SVG file, so even something quite small (eg. an attribute that shouldn't be allowed to have a null value having a null value) could cause it to fail.